# Dynamic HTML with Foundation and React

Tags: coffeescript, zurb-foundation, reactjs

I'm trying to use Foundation with React, but I'm experiencing some problems regarding dynamic creation of interactive content.

Here is some coffee script code which shall create a data-dropdown but I think the problem is more general so that it's independent of the code.

```
render : ->
  a href : '#', "data-dropdown" : 'drop',
    'Dropdown link text'
    div id : "drop", "data-dropdown-content" : true, className : "f-dropdown content",
      p 'Dropdown content text'
```

Normally, one could call the Foundation function on dynamically created HTML nodes, but I don't think that this harmonizes with the spirit of React.

Is there a best practice for this case? Or should I switch to React-Bootstrap?

I also tried to invoke the foundation method on the DOM nodes, but beside the fact that it doesn't work, it would be plain ugly.

Comment: I switched to (React-)Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not going to want to use foundation or bootstrap javascript in your reactjs code. It usually doesn't work at all. Moving to react-bootstrap like you have is probably the way to go,

http://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Here's a pretty awesome react resource to help find other react components if you need something specific,

http://react-components.com/